# How to set props before render in React

Tags: reactjs, components, state

can anyone tell me why, when I set state in my componentWillMount() method, a function within render() is run before the state is set, i.e

this is my App:

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      x : 50,
      y : 100,
      width : 200,
      height : 300
    }
    this.handleDuplicate = this.handleDuplicate.bind(this);
  }

  handleDuplicate(newDims){
    this.setState({newDims : newDims})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <svg id="svgOne" width="5000" height="3000">
          <NewRect 
            {...this.state}
            handleDuplicate={this.handleDuplicate}
          />
        </svg>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and this is my component, NewRect:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class NewRect extends Component {
  componentWillMount(){
    let { x, y, width, height } = this.props
    let newDims = {
      x : x + 30,
      y : y + 30,
      width : width - 50,
      height : height + 50
    }
    this.props.handleDuplicate(newDims);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
          <rect 
            x={this.props.x} 
            y={this.props.y} 
            width={this.props.width} 
            height={this.props.height} 
            fill="black" 
          />
    );
  }
}

export default NewRect;
```

As far as I was aware, the whole point of componentWillMount() was to complete all of the operations which need to be completed before render().

Comment: FYI, in eact 16 componentWillMount is considered legacy and may disaapear at some point, precisely because ots correct usage has pften been misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

setState is asynchronous, therefore you cannot assume that render is called with the new state.

What you can do is to create a state variable named "loading" or something similar, set its initial value to true, and set it to false in componentWillMount.

In render you will display a spinner when loading is still true.

BTW, I found it difficult to understand your code, but I am sure that React is smarter than me :) 
You pass the parent's state as props to your child component, which runs a function in the parent component that may change the parent's state, which is passed as props... Not the simplest thing to do, I hope that it works :)

I would try to think about a simpler way to do it, but I am not always right, far from it...

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is asynchronous. I suspect what's occurring is this:

1. `App.render()` is called
2. `NewRect` is instantiated
3. `NewRect.componentWillMount()` is called
4. `App.handleDuplicate()` is called
5. `App.setState()` is called
6. `NewRect.render()` is called
7. `App.setState()` change is executed
8. `App.render()` is called
9. New props are passed down to `NewRect`
10. `NewRect.render()` is called

Ultimately this should not matter. If it does, consider mirroring the state in `NewRect` or use a callback on `setState`. If your pattern relies on synchronous rendering, you may want to revisit your architecture. React is moving [toward fully asynchronous rendering](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html).